# JComponent partially hidden due to scrollpane in a BoxLayout

Tags: java, swing, layout-manager, boxlayout

I want to add the possibility for my users to add a comment on a form. To display them, I created JPanel inside a simple JScrollPane. I set the layout of this JPanel to `BoxLayout` because I wish to add them all in only one column and it seemed to be the easiest way by calling `BoxLayout.Y_AXIS` in the constructor. I also tried `GridLayout` and `GridBagLayout` but it was not what I was looking for.

My problem is that when a JPanel has the BoxLayout layout, it's width automatically is the same as it's container, but my container is a JScrollPane and the caret hides the right side of my comment!

[image: A picture is worth a thousand words.]

You can see the JTextField and a JButton on the bottom left, here's the code on the click event :

```
private void btnAjoutCommentaireActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {       
    //I take the text from the JTextField and format it to html                                      
    String formattedComment = "<html><br><div style='width:280px;'>" + 
            txtArCommentaire.getText().replaceAll("\n", "<br>") + 
            "</div><br></html>";

    JLabel label = new JLabel(formattedComment);
    //I add a blue border
    label.setBorder(new TitledBorder(new EtchedBorder(Color.lightGray, Color.blue), ConfigUser.getCu().toString()));
    //this below doesn't work
    label.setSize(280, 200);

    //I tried adding a JPanel in between but it didn't really worked out
    //JPanel panel = new JPanel();
    //panel.setLayout(new GridLayout(1, 1));
    //panel.setSize(297, 200);
    //panel.add(label);

    ///pnlCommentaire is the JPanel inside the JScrollPane

    pnlCommentaire.setLayout(new BoxLayout(pnlCommentaire, BoxLayout.Y_AXIS));

    pnlCommentaire.add(label);

    pnlCommentaire.revalidate();
    pnlCommentaire.repaint();
}
```

As you can see I tried to adust the size in html using `style='width:280px'`and on the JLabel using `label.setSize(280, 200);` but none of them worked.

Do you have any idea on how I could resize this Jlabel?

EDIT :

I added a `margin-right` property to the `div` so that I can at least fully see the text in the JLabel but the right border is still hidden.

```
 String formattedComment = "<html><br><div style='width:280px;margin-right:50px;'>" + 
            txtArCommentaire.getText().replaceAll("\n", "<br>") + 
            "</div><br></html>";
```

Comment: why don't you use windows builder.. it will make everything easy for you

Comment: @KaranMalhotra Well I used it to create the JScrollPane and Jpanel but the comments are added dynamically so there is no way to know in advance how many there will be,

Comment: For better help sooner, post a [MCVE] or [Short, Self Contained, Correct Example](http://www.sscce.org/).

Comment: @KaranMalhotra, `why don't you use windows builder..` - that is not a good solution. It is better to learn Swing and how to use layout managers to build an effective GUI.

Comment: yeah .. but isn't it little tough to design a gui without visualizing.